# Assert body of HTTP requests using requests_mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-requests, pytest

I am using [requests-mock](http://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with pytest to facilitate unit testing my library, which uses [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) for API calls.

In addition to mocking server responses, I often need to verify that my library sends the expected payload in the HTTP body.

I have been able to do this, albeit indirectly, using an [additional_matcher](http://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/matching.html#additional-matchers) callback in my tests:

```
def mylibrary_foo():
    """Library method that is under test."""
    r = requests.post('http://example.com/foo', data='hellxo')
    return r.text

@requests_mock.Mocker()
def test_foo(m):
    def matcher(request):
        assert request.body == 'hello'
        return True

    m.post('http://example.com/foo', text='bar', additional_matcher=matcher)

    result = mylibrary_foo()
    assert result == 'bar'
```

But it feels a little funny to be using the `additional_matcher` callback to verify the request format, as it is really intended to determine whether or not this particular request call should be mocked at all. Were I not using requests-mock, it seems I would be doing something more like:

```
def test_foo():
   # setup api_mock here...
   mylibrary_foo()
   api_mock.assert_called_with(data='hello')
```

Is there a pattern commonly used with requests-mock to support HTTP request verification?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I also haven't found any patterns in verifying if a request is called nor what the arguments are, but what I did might be more acceptable for you

```
def test_foo(m):
    ...
    adapter = m.post('http://example.com/foo', text='bar')
    result = mylibrary_foo()

    # for `called` or `call_count`
    assert adapter.call_count == 1
    assert adapter.called

    # for more in-depth checking of params/body, you can access `.last_request` and `.request_history` of `adapter`
    assert adapter.last_request.json() == {'foo': 'bar'}
    assert adapter.request_history[-1].json() == {'foo': 'bar'}
```

Comment: That is more along the lines of what I was hoping for, thank you. I notice the documentation is here: https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html